# MySQL should return row if subquery has no result

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-like, not-exists

I need a query and I'm trying something to achieve that but still can't solve my problem. I got a table and data stored in a field which is separated whit comma. So data looks like `'120,122,145,136'`. I called this table `table1`.

The other table has 1300 row. I'm trying to get rows, which is not included in table1.

Here is the query I wrote. This is not working correctly. How to get right result ?

```
SELECT a.ddd FROM table2 a 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT id 
       FROM table1 
       WHERE data_separated_comma NOT LIKE '%a.ddd%')
```

I hope someone help me.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing comma separated association is really a bad idea you should care to alter your schema and normalize it by using a junction table which holds the relation between your table1 and 2,For your current problem you can rewrite your query by using `find_in_set`

```
SELECT a.ddd 
FROM table2 a 
left join table1 b
 on(find_in_set(a.ddd,data_separated_comma ) > 0)
 WHERE b.id is null
```

[*Database Normalization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Yes you're right. I know, I need to normalize my table ASAP. But thank you anyway. I solved my problem with your query. That was fast reply.